# Problema com casas decimais

Tags: javascript

Galera tenho esse codigo em javascript que soma valores das checkboxes, por algum motivo ele só soma a primeira casa do valor, por exemplo, o valor é 1.75 ele soma somente 1.00, o codigo é esse.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          var containers = document.querySelectorAll("[data-calc]");

var Calculadora = function(container) {
  var self = this;
  self.container = container;

  self.hiddentotal = self.container.querySelector("input[name='hiddentotal']");
  self.total = self.container.querySelector("input[name='total']");
  self.tamanhos = [].slice.call(self.container.querySelectorAll("input[name='tamanho[]']"));
  self.asplos = [].slice.call(self.container.querySelectorAll("input[name='asplo[]']"));
  self.valores = [].slice.call(self.container.querySelectorAll("input[name='valor[]']"));

  var onChange = function (event) {
    self.onInputChange(event);  
  }

  this.tamanhos.forEach(function (tamanho, indice) {
    tamanho.addEventListener("change", onChange);
  });

    this.asplos.forEach(function (asplo, indice) {
    asplo.addEventListener("change", onChange);
  });

  this.valores.forEach(function (valor, indice) {
    valor.addEventListener("change", onChange);
  });
}

Calculadora.prototype.onInputChange = function (event) {
  //recuperando o valor do radio tamanho selecionado.
  var tamanho = this.tamanhos.filter(function (tamanho, indice) {
    return tamanho.checked
  })[0];  
  tamanho = tamanho ? parseFloat(tamanho.dataset.valor) : 0;


  var asplo = this.asplos.filter(function (asplo, indice) {
    return asplo.checked
  })[0];  
  asplo = asplo ? parseFloat(asplo.dataset.valor) : 0;

  //somando os valores selecionados.
  var valor = this.valores.reduce(function (atual, proximo, indice) {
    var valor = atual;
    if (atual instanceof HTMLElement) {
      valor = atual.checked ? parseInt(atual.dataset.valor) : 0;
    }
    if (proximo.checked) {
      valor += parseInt(proximo.dataset.valor)
    }
    return valor;
  });

  //não entendi o pq do seu total ser a soma do tamanho com os valores, mas isto já forge a parte tecnica.
  var total = tamanho + asplo + valor;

  //formando o total como currency.
  //este metodo não é suportado pelo IE abaixo do 11, assim como pelo Safari.
  //para os browsers acima citados, é necessario uar um Polyfill (sugestão: https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js)
  var format = total.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });

  this.hiddentotal.value = total
  this.total.value = format;  
};

var calculadoras = [];
[].forEach.call(containers, function (container, indice) {
  var calculadora = new Calculadora(container);
  calculadoras.push(calculadora);
});
        </script>
```

no html está assim

```
    <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="valor[]" value="Valornumero1" data-valor="1.50" />
Valornumero1
</label>
```

Comment: Olhei rapidamente e não testei, mas na parte que soma você esta usando "parseInt" então quando você passa um valor fracionado também conhecido como "float" ele está arredondando seus valores é o que a função faz, então basta troca para "parseFloat" que deve funcionar.

Comment: po, valeu cara, funcionou certinho, não manjo muito de javascript mas agora to começando a entender a logica

Comment: @SK15 podes colocar uma resposta...

Comment: como q poe como resposta? é vc q poe ou eu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem conforme eu já havia comentado e agora estou colocando como reposta, o problema do seu código é que você esta usando a função "[parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)" na hora da soma, sendo assim essa função do JavaScript faz com que todos dados passados por ela sejam transformados em números [Inteiros](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inteiro_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) não importando o tipo de dado seja String, Float ou Inteiros, fazendo com que afete sua soma, ainda mais caso use números fracionados, também conhecidos como [Ponto flutuante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_flutuante) *(o que engloba Float, Double ou Real)*, sendo assim a solução era usar a função "[parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)" para caso seja inseridos números 'quebrados' não afetasse a conta.

Um exemplo simples de como eles funcionam:

```
parseInt("10") // Entrada 10 String -> Saída 10 inteiro
parseInt("10.10") // Entrada 10.10 String -> Saida 10 Inteiro
parseInt(10) // Entrada 10 Inteiro -> Saída 10 Inteiro
parseInt(10.10) // Entrada 10.10 Float -> Saída 10 Inteiro

parseFloat("10") // Entrada 10 String -> Saída 10 inteiro
parseFloat("10.10") // Entrada 10.10 String -> Saida 10.10 Float
parseFloat(10) // Entrada 10 Inteiro -> Saída 10 Inteiro
parseFloat(10.10) // Entrada 10.10 Float -> Saída 10.10 Float
```

No seu código a parte que influencia é essa:

```
//somando os valores selecionados.
var valor = this.valores.reduce(function (atual, proximo, indice) {
var valor = atual;
if (atual instanceof HTMLElement) {
 // Linha antiga 
 // valor = atual.checked ? parseInt(atual.dataset.valor) : 0;

 // Linha nova corrigida
 valor = atual.checked ? parseFloat(atual.dataset.valor) : 0;
}
if (proximo.checked) {
 // Linha Antiga
 // valor += parseInt(proximo.dataset.valor)

 // Linha nova corrigida
 valor += parseFloat(proximo.dataset.valor)
}
 return valor;
});
```